# Java Performance: Where to find Hot Code tab in Java Mission Control 8 have they removed this functionality?

Tags: java, performance, jmc

I am exploring the Java Mission Control 8.3 version. In the tutorial to which I am referring, they are using an older version of Java Mission Control 7.X. In the tutorial, they show a "Code Flow" tab that contains a "Hot Methods" section. I am unable to find the "Code Flow" tab or the "HotCode". In Java Mission Control 8, have they removed the HotCode tab or functionality all together?

Tutorial Link:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-flight-recorder-monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of JMC you can go to the Method Profiling page:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for us to find heap size, time frame and memory stats for a particular method?

Comment: I have raised a separate question for the above. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75205766/java-performance-in-java-machine-control-how-to-find-heap-size-time-frame-and