# Java Performance: In Java Machine Control How to find heap size , time frame and memory stats for a particular method call

Tags: java, jmc

Using Java Mission Control is it possible for us to find heap size, time frame and memory stats for a particular method call. In method profiling section, I am unable for figure out those!!

Answer (score 0):

To find heap size, you can use the `totalMemory()` and `maxMemory()` methods of the Runtime class.

```
long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

To measure the time taken by a particular method call, you can use the System.nanoTime() method to get the current time before and after the method call and calculate the difference.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// method call here
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long duration = (endTime - startTime);
```

You can also use the `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` JVM option to get more detailed information about garbage collection and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

in `Memory` section | `Allocation` Tab, you can find out which where specified objects are allocated memory

in `Event` section | `Graph` , and `Thread` section | `Latencies` there is some information about function call time

you can read [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks001.html) and watch [these slides](https://www-acc.gsi.de/wiki/pub/Applications/AppWorkshopJava20150217/20150217_Java8WS_JavaMissionControl.pdf) , there are simple notes about `JMC`

Answer (score -1):

I've written a program to show you how to implement that in **JAVA**.
Please note that I am on **Mac** and I've run the program on **Netbeans IDE 16**.

Now, in the code below I used [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) to get the taken time to run the code inside **yourFunc()**

For more details [System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351571/12146581)

To get the **heap size** for the executed code [ManagementFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) class that has a function [getMemoryMXBean()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryMXBean()) which returns the managed bean for the memory system of the Java virtual machine.

Then with [getHeapMemoryUsage()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#getHeapMemoryUsage--) and [getUsed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html) that gets the size used to allocate objects in the program.

Also By using [totalMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()) & [freeMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory--), you can calculate the memory used by the function as shown below.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean;

/**
 *
 * @author ghaith
 */
public class JavaPerformance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        long totalMemoryBefore = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        long freeMemoryBefore = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        
        long timeBeforeCall = System.nanoTime();
        yourFunc();
        long timeAfterCall = System.nanoTime();
        
        long totalMemoryAfter = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        long freeMemoryAfter = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        long memoryUsed = (totalMemoryAfter - freeMemoryAfter) - (totalMemoryBefore - freeMemoryBefore);
        System.out.println("Memory used: " + memoryUsed / (1024 * 1024) + "MB");
        
        long timeSpentRunningTheFunc = timeAfterCall - timeBeforeCall;
        System.out.println("Elapsed Time: " + timeSpentRunningTheFunc + "ns");
        
        MemoryMXBean mBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
        System.out.println("Heap size: " + 
                mBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed() / (1024 * 1024) + "MB");
    }
    
    public static void yourFunc() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inside yourFunc with index " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Inside yourFunc with index 0
>
> ...
>
> Inside yourFunc with index 99999
>
> Memory used: 34MB
>
> Elapsed Time: 2603351891ns
>
> Heap size: 37MB